# Main Class - sub classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've just started AS3. I like to use proper programming methods when I program - and I'm not sure how to write code in the symbol classes that is recognized by the main document class.
If I put all my code into the document class it works fine - but WHAT a mess!!!  Surely this can't be how it's supposed to be done?

I've been away from any programming for 3 years, and now am struggling to 'catch up'. Can someone offer the simplest example of main document class calling/accessing information in a symbol class?  It would be really appreciated! If I initiate a variable in the main class I know it goes over to the symbol class and checks that public class and public function, but if I put ANYTHING in there (ie: even the variable xy coordinates) my program craps out.

Thank you in advance for any help with this - it seems so basic, it's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has tips for creating a basic AS3 application here:

[Adobe, creating basic application](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000219.html)

Colin Moock's book, Essential ActionScript Chapter 29 has a good explanation on how to program the symbol instances.